# How can I figure out what anonymous memory is being used for?

Tags: jvm, java

I have a program which is not running out of heap but for which the use of anonymous/native memory grows and grows. How can I go about figuring out what is using this memory?

Comment: Java HPROF? HPROF: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html

Answer (score 0):

Inspect a heap dump for `DirectByteBuffer` objects and what's holding onto them. File mappings would also be a cause, but you say anonymous mappings so that's probably not the issue here since those would be named.

For some things [native memory tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) may be useful too.

If it's neither DirectByteBuffer instances nor other memory pools managed by the VM it might be some native library used by your application.

Comment: Thanks! How do I get a heap dump for DirectByteBuffer?