# Java process size is huge. Any ability to reduce it?

Tags: process, jvm, virtual-machine

I have several processes (JVMs) that are using huge amount of memory.

I'm starting the JVM with no -Xms value and with 2G or 3G in -XmX.
heap is stable and doesnt seems to have any leak or other issues. GC works perfect...

But... the process size and the VIRT value are huge. most are 10G-15G and even one is 20G !!!

Java used is 1.7 and working on VM installed with RH linux 6.5

I understand that the process size will be higher then the heap size as there is more than just objects :) but I've never seen such a huge addon...

Any idea what might cause that? any idea how we can reduce it?

Thanks a lot!
Ori

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/33573214/1362755 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/31178912/1362755

Comment: You needed to find out what is using the memory. I suggest you try `/proc/{pid}/maps` as a start.